# Save data from Kafka topic to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm learning Spark streaming and trying to save my sample Stock data (just strings like "MSFT:28.29") received from Kafka topic to Cassandra using spark-streaming and Cassandra Spark connector.

Without saving to Cassandra my code works fine (get data from Kafka and do some trivial statistics calculation). Cassandra is configured and connection is established as well.

But if I'm trying to add below line to save raw data to Cassandra table before processing:

```
 stockParsed.saveToCassandra("dashboard","raw_tick")
```

in Spark streaming UI I see 1 batch hanging in "Processing" state and all the rest - in status "Queued" and no any data in Cassandra.

In Spark console I see only the lines like:

```
16/02/16 10:18:40 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1455635920000 ms
16/02/16 10:18:50 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1455635930000 ms
16/02/16 10:19:00 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1455635940000 ms
```

Here is my code:

```
case class Stock(ticker: String, price: Double)
// ....

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaStream").setMaster("local[*]")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms","60000")
  .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb","1")

val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))

val topicMap = Map("test" -> 1)

val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "test-group", topicMap).map(_._2)

val stockParsed = lines.map(line => line.split(':')).map(s => Stock(s(0).toString, s(1).toDouble))

//Problem here
stockParsed.saveToCassandra("dashboard","raw_tick",SomeColumns("ticker", "price"))

//Some processing below
```

My build.sbt:

```
import sbt.Keys._

name := "KafkaStreamSbt"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0"  % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-assembly" % "1.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector-java" % "1.5.0-RC1"
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.16"
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have at least 2 cores assigned?

Comment: 2 cores for what? I'm starting Spark locally with "local[*]" option

Comment: That should set all cores on the machine as available. You need at least one executor core to run the receiver (if you are running in receiver mode) If there is only one core available you can only run the receiver and not actually process data.

Comment: How to configure it? I have 4 cores on this VM

Comment: The * should set it to 4 then. You can always explicitly do local[4] too. If that doesn't fix it I would check your executor logs

Answer (score 0):

Question solved: I had an error in Cassandra keyspace configuration. After recreation of keyspace with this script:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE tutorial WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};
```

code works fine.